# "window.frames[0].variable" doesn't work in jquery $(function(){})?

Tags: jquery, variables, frame, quote

In `parent.html` I set an iframe with `child.html` in it.

in child frame,I write js:

```
$(function () { 
    var child = 6;
})
```

in parent frame,I write js:

```
$(function () {
    alert(window.frames[0].child);
});
```

but the alert result is "undefined"?

How can I quote another frame's variable correctly with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing `undefined` because you're delcaring it as a local variable (scoped only to that `document.ready` handler), you would need this in the child frame for a global:

```
$(function () { 
    window.child = 6;
});
```

Also, there's no guarantee that a `document.ready` on the parent frame won't execute *before* the child frame (stick an `alert()` in each to see the order)...in fact it should be the opposite.  If you're not using it immediately, it's not an issue...if you are you need to execute it later.

Comment: In fact, it still does not work the case above,I think you are right, the “alert()” execute order can not be controled……but in my other cases, the global variable actually works ,I need not get using it immediately……Thank you solved my problem!